# Visual artifacts in apps on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: graphics, 22.04, amd-graphics, amdgpu, visual-artifacts

After a clean installation of Ubuntu 22.04, I'm facing this problem in some apps such as Firefox. When installing OBS through the store, it also stays like this and I already had this problem before. Sometimes Chrome would bug which is a big problem.

[image]

My specs are:

- AMD Ryzen 5 5600X 6-Core Processor 3.70 GHz
- 48.0GB RAM
- 5500XT 4GB
- SSD NVME 1TB

EDIT:

Loot at spotify for example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g9Dp.jpg)